# mongoose update data information, how to prevent overwrite

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So i was trying to update data store in the mongodb database, using Mongoose
original data structure looks like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("234u232kjrkjwebrkw"),
    "local" : {
        "password" : "sdflsdjflsdjlfkjsdlkfjklsdjflksd",
        "email" : "email@email.com"
    },
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I'm trying to update the "userName" property in the "local". after which it supposed to be

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("234u232kjrkjwebrkw"),
    "local" : {
        "password" : "sdflsdjflsdjlfkjsdlkfjklsdjflksd",
        "email" : "email@email.com",
        "userName" : "yowhatsup"
    },
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I used this

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate("54a490ab6e13cca1d47870d6", {local:{ userName: 'jasonBorne' }}, { upsert: true }, function(){})
```

it became this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("234u232kjrkjwebrkw"),
    "local" : {
        "userName" : "yowhatsup"
    },
    "__v" : 0
}
```

it's been overwritten. 
how to avoid this?

note: the new "userName" is defined as {type:String,default:null} when the model was structred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do an an update if exists, otherwise insert:

Arguments for update are: findQuery, data, queryOptions, onComplete

```
User.update({"_id" : ObjectId("234u232kjrkjwebrkw")}, { $set: { "local.userName": "whatsup" } }, { upsert: true }, function(err){...});
```